# 404 error when calling REST api (Phalcon)

Tags: php, ajax, apache, http-headers, phalcon

I am receiving a 404 error when trying to call a DELETE or a PUT in Phalcon using ajax. I am able to do a GET.

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/person/blah/5',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

My PHP

```
$app->delete('/person/blah/{id:[0-9]+}', function($id) {
    $response = new Phalcon\Http\Response();
    $response->setJsonContent(array('status' => 'OK', 'data' => array('id' => $id)));
    return $response;  
});
```

Prior to this I was getting CORS issues with DELETE, PUT and GET. I changed my .htaccess file to allow access control and the GET started to work. However, I am now having 404 issues with DELETE and PUT.

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "DELETE, PUT, GET"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
</IfModule>
```

My guess is that this issue is related to CORS. The javascript is running on my computer (not server). My javascript is in C:/Users/username/Desktop/test.html. I have tried in both Firefox and Chrome and have the same issue.

---

Some extra information

response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    DELETE, PUT, GET
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  15
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 10 Feb 2015 00:25:17 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9
Status  404 Not Found
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.9
access-control-allow-orig...    *
```

request header

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Me...    DELETE
Connection  keep-alive
DNT     1
Host    localhost
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/35.0
```

response header from cache is same as response header

If it matters I have been able to successfully call my DELETE using curl.

```
$ curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost/person/blah/5
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Feb 2015 23:18:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, PUT, GET
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: text/html

{"status":"OK","data":{"id":"5"}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't have everything I needed in my .htaccess file.

I followed this guide
http://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/

I needed this:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Comment: The best way would be to handle this in the code.. But this work nicely as well.

Comment: True, but this works just fine, because Chrome does a OPTIONS before doing the POST and because of the 404 error will not continue, we don't need OPTIONS but we don't want it to stop at this, we want to continue processing, given you 1 point after lots of search this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to follow the flow chart and see what you've missed:
http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png

If you are taking advantage of cookies or need response headers exposed you will need to turn on

Access-Control-Expose-Headers

and

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Might want to try using them even if you aren't.